# Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder in Android

Tags: java, android, slf4j

One of our dependency is a java library that uses SLF4J as logger, we need and we use this library in one of our Android project but it seems SLF4J logger is not working by default in the platform. We didn't add any logger dependency as Android seems to have it by default when we tried to import it, so far this is the log warning that we are getting.

```
Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
```

The log also provides a [link](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) suggesting a way to fix it but we can't fully understand it. Is there a way to make it work with the Android platform? The logs coming from the library is very important for us to investigate one of our issues we are facing in the project.

Sample code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SOME_UTIL.class);

// some function
log.info("Start dump data");
log.debug("Parsing config from classpath file {}", path);
```